# name attribute inhibits onclick function

Tags: javascript, css, post, onclick

The code below works fine, it changes the type of password to reveal the input as text.
The prolem appears when adding a name attribut to "password" in order to retrieve data from $POST in php. I thought there might be a way to get the data on serverside without a "name", but my reasearch showed that without a "name" attribute no data can be retrieved.

Question: How to bring in the name attribute and keep my functionality?

```
            <div>
                <label for="password">Passwort (8 min. pls. )</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" minlenght="8" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="anzeigen">Passwort anzeigen</label>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="anzeigen()" >
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" id="mitmachen" value="mitmachen">
            </div>
        </form>
        <script>
            function anzeigen() {
                var x = document.getElementById("password");
                if (x.type === "password") {
                    x.type = "text";
                }else {
                    x.type = "password";
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: `The prolem appears when adding a name attribut to "password" in order to retrieve data from $POST in php.`. Where is the relevant PHP code and call? [How to Create a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The `name` attribute should have no effect on your JS. Please create a runnable snippet in which we can experience your issue. Do note that the `for` attribute should have the same value as the `id`, which is missing on your checkbox.

Comment: This works fine as-is, including when adding a name attribute to the pw field (I used "pw" and "password"). But you don't include a name here, so we don't know what you've used or if it's conflicting with other variables. Please elaborate on what actually happens when you include a name attribute. Is there an error in the console? What have you done to debug it?

Comment: Heyho, so I have to say sorry, the way I asked was bad. I was a bit grumpy yesterday. It turned out that I asked the wrong question. It is not about the name attribute but abbout the naming of the <input type="checkbox" -> id, which can not be named the same as the onclick function of the <input type="checkbox". In my case (which is not pictured in the code above, sorry again) both had the name "anzeigen". After I changed the id's name to "an" it worked well. I am still interested why.